How do I get the old CTRL-T dialog in Visual Studio 2022 17.10?
I upgraded to Visual Studio 2022 17.10 yesterday and have realized CTRL-T (Go to All) has been revamped.  Is there a way to go back to the old version (it was just a small dialog that appeared in the top right corner).
The main reason I don't like the new one is that its behavior is inconsistent and it's slow compared to old CTRL-T.
Old Dialog (what I want):

New Dialog (what I don't like):

